# Every Screensaver in XScreensaver is showing in Show Applications

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop, appmenu, xscreensaver

So I just updated `xscreensaver`, and after doing so, every single individual screensaver is showing up as its own application in the "Show Application" menu.

I looked in my `/usr/share/applications` folder and there is a folder called screensaver containing all those "applications".

Is there anyway to move this folder out of this location? Since it is a root folder I am unable to delete or move files manually.

Comment: I'd like to know if you have resolved the issue as I have exactly the same problem since I upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10...
Many thanks,
Philippe

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Copy the folder containing all the `.desktop` launchers associated to those screensavers from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/`.
2. Open the copied `.desktop` files in the folder with a text editor.
3. Add the following `NoDisplay` line (or change if it already exists) to all the files

   ```
   NoDisplay=true
   ```
4. Save the files.

Comment: There is no applications folder in ~/.local/share/ on my system and the option to create a new folder in that location is grayed out.

Comment: @N.Betland What's your Ubuntu version and flavour? What's the output of `ls -l ~/.local/share/`?